# How can I copy-paste audio effect to other audio clips in VideoPad?

Tags: audio, effects

I took quite an effort to specify an Amplify audio effect with changing levels (in and out). I have more audio clips there for which I would like this effect too. Is it possible somehow copy-paste the audio effect to those audio clips?

I know it is possible to set the effect for multiple clips at once, but it is too late, the effect is already specified for only one clip now.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found it!

1. Click the disquette icon: "Save template" to save the audio effect template.
2. In the clip(s) you want to copy the effect to, click the green plus icon to load the template.

The effect will be then added to the clip(s) with all its settings.